# Getting records for date only from datetime for the last 7 days from current day in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can anyone help me, i have a string which passes date as (YY-mm-dd) eg. 2012-11-16. I want to get records from my database using PHP to get records for the last 7 days. My database contains unix timestamp in date&time format. How can I get records for the past 7 days from current day using PHP.

Comment: [huh ?!](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Getting+records+for+date+only+from+datetime+for+the+last+7+days)

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what database you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(yourdate) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This works on a "per day" basis. Use this to be accurate on second basis:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE yourdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```